# Detecting if your server is down using query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote the following code to make XHR requests to a heartbeat endpoint on my server every 2 seconds. Depending on success or failure I continue the execution or block the UI using Jquery UI block plugin.

```
var uiBlocked = false;
window.setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: 'HEAD',
  url: '/heartbeat/',
  timeout: 1000,
  success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
   if (uiBlocked == true && navigator.onLine) {
      uiBlocked = false;
      $.unblockUI();
     }
   },
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (uiBlocked == false){
        uiBlocked = true;
        $.blockUI({
           message: "Lost connectivity, please reconnect your VPN.",
           css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
          } });
   }
  }
})
}, 2000);
```

Now my entire UI gets cached at the client and the next calls are ajax calla that change part of the page. The problem is that some of these calls block for more than 2 seconds and at that time the page blocks and user is alerted for connectivity.

How do I avoid this false positive effectively? I cannot increase the timeout value because if I do make the timeout to lets 10 seconds, what if the end user makes a blocking call at the 9th second which blocks for 3 seconds, then again I will get a false positive.

Is there a workaround this situation.

Comment: You need a way to pause execution of your timeout. I would turn this into a `.queue()`/`.dequeue()` pattern, and when you have a blocking operation, set a variable that disables the check. Then, when the blocking operation is finished, re-enable the check.

Comment: That's essentially what I need to do , but there is no efficient way to check when there is a blocking operation

Comment: Don't make blocking calls.  And, 2 seconds is ridiculous.  Use a much higher timeout limit.  Why can't you let the user do whatever they want client-side, and then synchronize when you are able to to your backend?

Comment: "Why can't you let the user do whatever they want client-side". Is there a way to check on the client side that the end user is done. Much higher timeout poses the same issues i have explained in the question

Comment: @user567797 *"Is there a way to check on the client side that the end user is done."* define *"done"*

Comment: done means that I know for sure that I can now make the call to heartbeat without user making any calls that will block

Comment: There is no way of knowing that 100% unless you restrict the user. Why do you need blocking calls?

Comment: Blocking calls are made when we fetch some data from the DB. I was thinking of retrying the ajax request upon failure for lets say 5 times and if every time I get an error that would give me some degree of confidence in lost connectivity.